How to solve "Invalid uri specification. Option 'uri' value must be a wild card URI."
When I run this query
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS (   uri=CONCAT('gs://gcp_monthly_consumption/GCP_Consumption_Data/_GCP_Consumption_', FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),'.csv'),   format= 'csv',   overwrite=true,   header=true,   field_delimiter=',' ) AS

the name of my file in the bucket it writes to is 000000000000_GCP_Consumption_202403.csv. When removing the wildcard "*", I get the error How to solve "Invalid uri specification. Option 'uri' value must be a wild card URI."
Aim: get the file name to GCP_Consumption_202403.csv

I believe wildcards are required for uri as exporting tables usually intended to produce multiple files.
... _GCP_Consumption_', FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),'*.csv')
...

